# does the latest MikTeX version 21.2 work under Windows 7?

Tags: miktex, windows

In the MikTeX site, the prerequisites for MikTeX version 21.2 are listed as follows:

https://miktex.org/kb/prerequisites

MiKTeX prerequisites
Windows

MiKTeX for Windows requires one of the following Windows operating systems:

```
Windows 10
Windows Server 2016
Windows 8/8.1 (all editions except RT)
Windows Server 2012
```

Windows 7 was not listed.

But in CTAN, Windows 7 is still listed as working with MikTeX 21.2:

https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex?lang=en

Was the listing of Windows 7 in CTAN a misprint, or was it un-updated info?

My question is whether MikTeX 21.2 works under Windows 7.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I'm running MiKTeX under Win 7 Pro, and I can guarantee I have no problem.

Comment: Do you run the latest version 21.2 of MikTeX on Windows 7 ?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: @Bernard - Great.  Thank you very much.  I hesitated to upgrade MikTeX from 2.9 to 21.2 on my old Dell laptop running Windows 7 (not Pro), since I was concerned about wasting time to uninstall 21.2 to reinstall 2.9.

Comment: Seems this is a common problem https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/698882/unable-to-install-new-packages-on-miktex

Comment: For Windows7, please go with 32 bit installation

Comment: With unresolved problems in installing MikTeX under Windows 7, I decided to switch to Texlive, which has been working beautifully.   You don't need MikTeX for Windows 7.  I use Texlive (instead of MikTeX) as backend for TexStudio.

Answer (score 1):

Confirming that as of November 2023 MiKTex 21.1 works beautifully in Windows 7, in my case 7 pro x64.

Comment: I had problem with installing MikTeX in Windows 7, and decided to use TeXLive, which has been working beautifully for both TeX Studio and Inkscape with Textext.

Comment: Latest version to support Win7 is MiKTeX 22.7

Comment: @DanD-man no, now even previous versions of MikTeX don't work anymore on Windows 7: https://miktex.org/announcement/legacy-windows-deprecation

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is outdated, the current state is:

- Miktex 21.1, 21.2, ... are not working anymore on Windows 7
- Miktex 24 is not working on Window 7
- even versions that used to work on Windows 7 (e.g. Miktex 2.9) are now unable to install packages

See also : https://miktex.org/announcement/legacy-windows-deprecation

I am curious is there is a solution to make 2.9 work on Windows 7?

Comment: See my comment on using Texlive, which can be used as a backend for TexStudio, in Windows 7 above.