# Unable to install new packages on MiKTeX

Tags: packages, miktex, winedt

I've been having trouble recently to install new packages from online sources, using MiKTeX + WinEdt.

Through WinEdt:

[image]

and then:

[image]

the following error occurs:

[image]

The text of the error message is "SSL connect error" and "code="35", url="https://api2.miktex.org/hello"". I have googled and saw many people had this issue, but what resolved to most people was a deactivation of the firewall or attempting a different internet connection. I have tried them both to no avail. This is not a firewall/internet connection issue (Or at least, not one that is fixed by either of these 2 options).

I checked online on miktex's website, and was surprised to discovered they only support Windows 10 and upwards. I am on Windows 7, and used MiKTeX 2.9. They have blocked installation of current MiKTeX versions for Windows older than 10.

I have read another solution online which suggested reinstalling MiKTeX. Sadly, I did so, and found MiKTeX 22.7 which still works on Windows 7 (It is the latest version to work on Windows older than 10).

I was referred to MiKTeX Console Manager, which yields to pretty much the same problem:

[image]
[image]

So I tried changing the repository:

[image]

I have tried several proxy servers found online, but none succeeded.

[image]

What is very unfortunate is that I had some of the packages installed earlier, but after uninstalling the previous MiKTeX and reinstalling 22.7, I have pretty much none now.

Is it related to MiKTeX not supporting Windows lower than 10? How can I overcome this?

Comment: well the obvious solution would be to update your windows. The alternative would be to get packages from ctan and to install them manually as in the old days before all these nice package managers were written. But that can get rather tedious. Why are you surprised that a free software stops to support an operating system that has reached his end-of-life some years ago?

Comment: My local MikTeX repository occasionally closes down for maintenence, etc.  Try agian in a few days.

Comment: What works for me is a) using a package, even a new one, in a regular Latex-document,  b) compile. Because of my configuration the MikTeX console asks me to download and install any missing packages. This can take a while, sometimes downloading several dependencies. // Updating the whole installation is no problem either: Check for Updates in the console.

Comment: I have tried checking for updates in MiKTeX's console, but I get the same error message.

Comment: If miktex gives you trouble, maybe have a look at texlive instead (no idea if it works with old windows version, I'm not a windows user)? This site https://tug.org/texlive/windows.html only mentions that windows xp and 32 bit is no compatible with the current version.

Comment: The TeX Live Guide 2023 says "Windows 7 and later are supported. Windows Vista may still mostly work", see https://tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-40001.2.

Comment: At a guess (without a serious investigation, as I don't have a Windows 7 machine to hand), the error appears to be that the SSL connection at the MikTeX end has a protocol version of SSL/TLS that Windows 7 doesn't. If this is the case, there is almost nothing you can do to make it work, short of setting up a local proxy on a machine with Win 10, or a modern Linux, which can connect to the MikTeX server. A local proxy on the Windows 7 machine can't help with this issue, as the SSL/TLS on Win7 is the problem.