# Snapshot/backup of CTAN Miktex packages as of 2020

Tags: packages, miktex, ctan

Ten years ago, some distributors (such as MikTex) provided a download link for an ISO DVD containing a snapshot of all CTAN MikTex packages.

For some reasons, I would like a snapshot of (possibly all) CTAN MikTex packages, as of 2020 for example.

Which sources provide such an archive?

Comment: What are the "some reasons" exactly? If it is about the actual LaTeX packages (`.sty` and `.cls` files) then you can get them from https://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/ctancd/ or https://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/texlive/. That site doesn't have the Windows executables for `pdflatex` etc available however I think.

Comment: Not quite what you asked, but maybe what you need: Overleaf keeps past TeX Live versions to support old projects, so you can actually choose on which TL version to run your project. I think they go back as far as TL 2014.

Comment: @Marijn reasons: I use a few computers: some of them are on Win10, some of them have to stay on Win7 because of legacy software (important for my activity) which don't work on Win10. I can imagine lots of other people having specific situations requiring to stay on Win7 because of legacy software situations.

Comment: Ok, so it is specifically about the MikTeX binaries, and not about the packages. That is useful information to give you some more pointers, such as the related/duplicate questions https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527952/are-previous-releases-of-miktex-available, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695629/getting-older-versions-of-miktex-can-it-be-raplaced-with-texlive, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/588249/does-the-latest-miktex-version-21-2-work-under-windows-7. So the answer seems to be "not really" unless you want to compile from source.

Comment: However, TeX Live also runs on Windows, and for that you can go much further back to releases that support Windows 7 using the links from my first comment.

Comment: Thanks you for this information @Marijn! PS: no it's not about the MikTeX binaries (I have them), it's about a 2020 snapshot of the packages, ready to be installed in MikTeX (there is *MikTex-specific* metadata files I think), which can be found in CTAN `/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages`: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages